# Android, 2 spinners

Tags: android, android-intent, android-spinner

I new to android programming and I feel like I'm bashing my head of a brick wall.

I'm trying to set up two spinners so when the item is selected in spinner one it brings up a new list of items in spinner two, but the problem is the spinner one has 4 items and each item I would like to bring up different information on the second spinner and if that's not enough when the item in the second spinner is selected I would like it to like to another set of information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make your activity implement onItemSelectedListener, and bind the spinners to it like this:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then, you'll want to use the onItemSelected method to change the data set for the second spinner, sort of like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
   if( parent == spinner1 ) {
          if( pos == 0 ) {
             ArrayAdapter<String> newAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newDataSet1);
             newAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
             spinner2.setAdapter(newAdapter);
          } else if( pos == 1 ) {
              //etc
          }
   }
}
```

and you could add a second clause to the outer if, checking if parent was equal to spinner2, and substitute other data sets for a third spinner like that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution, in my opinion, is to define your listeners inline or to define them as inner classes of your `Activity`.

Example:

***`layout.xml`***

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**`MyActivity.java`**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner spinnerOne = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_1);
        Spinner spinnerTwo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_2);
        spinnerOne.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                spinnerTwo.setAdapter(/*set new information in spinner 2 here*/);
            }
        });
    }
}
```